# How to load currency block in controller

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, blocks, ajax

I have created multi-currency selector in header using following logic

Updated app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/layout/local.xml as per follow

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="directory/currency" name="my_currency_selector" template="currency/currency.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>`

In `app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/page/html/header.phtml` added:

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_currency_selector') ?>`

Its works perfectly fine.

Now problem is that, I have ajax call on list page because of this I need to reload `my_currency_selector` in controller. 
I used following code which return me breadcrumbs block html.
`$breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml();`
But same code is not working for currency. I tried 
`$currency = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('my_currency_selector')->toHtml();`

Please tell me What I am mising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax action you perform has it's own layout handle, and usually AJAX calls don't load the `default` layout handle.
This means that your block does not exist in the ajax call.
You need to add this block in the layout handle for your ajax call and it should work nicely.

Comment: As `breadcrumbs` loads without adding it to layout handle for ajax call. I think problem is that `my_currency_selector` is inside `header`. First I have to load `header` and then `my_currency_selector`.

Comment: You are indeed right! same as all time